# FEP 2010 install fails: Error: Setup cannot determine the SQL Integration Service version

Tags: sql, sccm

When I try to install FEP2010 combined with SCCM R3 and SQL 2008 STD, I get this error:

Error: Setup cannot determine the SQL Integration Service version.
Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection 2010 requires Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2005 Enterprise or Standard edition with Service Pack 2 or higher or Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2008 Enterprise or Standard edition or higher.
Make sure that the component is installed, running and auto-started on server server.domain.ok.

The services are started, and set to auto-start with the local system account.

Any pointers on how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by reinstalling the SQL required features.